# Why doesn't matplotlib use the specified font here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

(Using Python 3.6.1 on Win10, in a virtualenv that basically just has numpy/pandas/matplotlib installed, for number-crunching stuff. I don't have Tkinter installed and would prefer to keep it that way.)

I have the following test code, attempting to render MathML text statically:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot


def render(mathml):
    plot.clf()
    plot.rc('font', family='monospace', size=72)
    plot.axis('off')
    plot.text(0, 0, f'{mathml}')
    plot.savefig(f'hax.png')


render('$lorem^{ipsum}$')
```

The resulting `test.png` shows the text in the default font (DejaVu Sans Oblique), not in a monospace font:

[image: improperly rendered text]

Explicitly specifying a font (e.g. `family='Courier New'`) also has no effect, and neither does changing the output format. The text is properly resized, and no error or warning appears - the output just doesn't show the right font.

What's going on here? How can I fix it?

Comment: *I don't have Tkinter installed and would prefer to keep it that way*, `tkinter` is already apart of the Python Standard Library, so its already installed.

Comment: It is entirely possible with the Windows standard installer to omit it (along with IDLE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options for math fonts are according to [the tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html)

> DejaVu Sans (default), DejaVu Serif, the Computer Modern fonts (from (La)TeX), STIX fonts (with are designed to blend well with Times), or a Unicode font that you provide

Sticking with the default, you can get a "typewriter"-like feeling using `\mathtt`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def render(mathml):
    plt.clf()
    plt.rc('font', size=72)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.text(0, 0, f'$\\mathtt{{{mathml}}}$')
    plt.show()

render('lorem^{ipsum}')
```

[image]

To use at custom fontset for mathtext is possible via the `mathtext.fontset` rc parameter.

```
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "custom"
```

For courier new font, this could look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def render(mathml):
    plt.clf()
    plt.rc('font', size=72)
    plt.rc('mathtext', fontset="custom", tt="Courier New")
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.text(0, 0, f'$\\mathtt{{{mathml}}}$')
    plt.show()

render('lorem^{ipsum}')
```

[image]

Comment: It hadn't even occurred to me that a separate method might be needed to choose a font for MathML text vs. ordinary text. I tested the original code with a plain `'lorem ipsum'` string and it did work.

Trying this approach, at first I got an error that `\mathtt{` is an unknown symbol. This was misleading - I had forgotten to strip the `$` from the test input, so presumably the rendering engine just saw `$\mathtt{$` followed by garbage.

Working beautifully now. Thanks :)